# How to convert a PDF file to a DOC file using Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there any module available for this? I tried searching on Google but didn't find. Let me know if there exists any.

Comment: LibreOffice Draw is able to open PDF as aligned containers of text, you can embed these in a Writer document and export to the target format. This works in a manual process. [perluno](http://perluno.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/perluno/?view=tar) might be able to automate that, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system?

If it's Windows, then (not nice) Win32::OLE could in theory automate this via a tool of some form, there are several available if you Google for "pdf to word converter".

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for
First read pdf with [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.57/lib/CAM/PDF.pm)

Then write as a word file with [Word::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/~johanl/Win32-Word-Writer-0.03/lib/Win32/Word/Writer.pm)

Comment: [CAM::PDF works just fine anywhere, you know?](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=CAM-PDF)